# How to Get a class with Jquery and perform a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am currently working on a project that deals with feed from a website.
I have successufully gotten the feed, but my challenge is getting the content and title of the feed when a user click on the feed link rather than taken the user to the feed site.

I have tried using different method to get the solution, but none works.

Below is my latest code (Jquery Mobile)

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.FeedEk=function(opt){
        var def={FeedUrl:'', MaxCount:5, ShowDesc:true, ShowPubDate:true, ShowFullContent:true};
        if(opt){
            $.extend(def,opt)
        }
        var idd = $(this).attr('id');
        if(def.FeedUrl==null || def.FeedUrl==''){
            $('#'+idd).empty();
            return;
        }
        var pubdate;
        $('#'+idd).empty().append('<div style="text-align:center; margin: auto;"><img src="loader.gif" class="loader" /></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num='+def.MaxCount+'&output=json&q='+encodeURIComponent(def.FeedUrl)+'&callback=?',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                $('#'+idd).empty();
                $('#post').empty();
                var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
                $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries,function(i,entry){
                    var i =new Array(i);
                    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
                        {
                            var id = j;
                        }
                    var title =new Array(entry.title);
                    var content =new Array(entry.content);
                    for(t=0;t<title.length;t++){
                        for(c=0;c<content.length;c++){$('#post').append(title[t]+'<br/>'+content[c])}
                    }
                    //while(id == 
                        //if(i == id
                        //var post = '<div><h3>'+entry.title+'</h3></div>';
                        //post += '<div>Post content'+entry.content+'</div>';
                    output += '<li>';
                    output += '<a href="#postContent" class="ItemTitle '+id+'">'+entry.title+'</a>';
                    /*if(def.ShowPubDate){
                        pubdate=new Date(feed[0].entry.publishedDate);
                        output += '<br/><span class="ItemDate">'+pubdate.toLocaleDateString()+'</span';
                    }
                    if(def.ShowDesc){
                        output += '<br/><span class="ItemDesc">'+feed[0].entry.contentSnippet+'</span>';
                    }*/
                    output += '</li>';});
            console.log(data.responseData.feed.entries);
            output += '</ul>';
            $('#'+idd).html(output);
                if($('.'+id).click() == true){
                    $('#post').empty();
                    var postTitle = title[id];
                    var postContent = content[id];
                    $('#post').append('<div><h3>'+postTitle+'</h3></div><div>'+postContent+'</div>');
                }
            }
        })

    }
    })
    (jQuery);
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>News on the GO!</title>
    <link href="theme/news.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="theme/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="theme/FeedEk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery1.7.2-min.js" ></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/FeedEk.js"></script>

    <link href="theme/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src='js/main.js'></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //latest
            $("#ipaid").FeedEk({
              FeedUrl : 'http://ipaidabribenaija.com/news?format=feed',
              MaxCount : 7,
              ShowDesc : true,
              ShowPubDate:true,
              ShowFullContent:true
            });});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <h2>Recent News</h2>
            <a href="#about" data-icon="info" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="dialog">About</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div class="imghome">
            <img src="images/news.png" alt="news" width="300" height="200" />
        </div>
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#latest" data-theme="a" data-transition="flip" >Local News</a></li></ul>
        </nav>
        <!--<div data-role="content" >
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"></div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /Page home -->

    <div data-role="page" id="latest" data-title="Local News">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="ipaid_header" data-theme="a">
            <h2>Local News</h2>
            <a href="#home" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-theme="a">Back</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content" >
            <div id="ipaid">
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="ipaid_footer" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="a">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#politics" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Politics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#world" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Sports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Business</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div><!-- /Footernavbar --></div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /Page Latest --></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You mean if a user clicks on _Politics_ it creates a new page with _Politics_ news feed?

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JE2ps/ still working on it, but I got what you want.

Comment: @omar What i want is once the feed is loaded and the user clicks on a link, the link will take the to a page called #postContent. Inside #postContent there is a #post. Now i want the title and content of that particular clicked link to appear in #post.

Comment: Check this [link/example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JE2ps/). Click on local news, then click any news link. This is what you want right?

Comment: @omar that is not what i want, i want the title link to be linking to a #page, the the full content and title for that particlar link to appear on that page once the link is clicked e.g `<a href="#postContent" >Feed Title</a>` once its clicked `<div id="postContent"><div id="post">feed title<br/>feed Content</div></div>

Comment: I can get the full content link the example you gave, but i don't want it to show the full content, so i decide to use the contentSnippet and title. So when they click on the link they can be able to see the full content and title for that particular link.

Comment: You want to copy the content of the feed into a new page, right? rather than opening a new browser window and leave your web?

Comment: Yes, i want the content of the feed for that PARTICULAR CLICKED link appear in a new page

Comment: Have you check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JE2ps/) it does exactly what you want. Click on any feed, it will create a new page and loads the page contents. its not complete yet, as I wasn't sure what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: @omar can you pls explain to me how this solution works so i can include in to my script. I am guessing you worked with DOM to get the content.

Comment: I'm getting the contents from the same feed `li`, it contains all the information you need.

Comment: @omar Thanks alot, you have giving me a good clue on how i can use it to mmy advantage. I can work with your solution.

Comment: @omar can i email you when am done with it? Also .parent() is it a $ method?

Comment: my email is omarmt[at]gmail.com

Comment: Also make you solution an answer so i can tick it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood. You want to show each news feed on a separate page on your webpage, and prevent the *link* from opening a new window (leaving your webpage).

You could do the following, of course it needs some tuning and CSS styling, which can be done easily. The below code, prevents opening the link a new window, - using `preventDefault()` - it copies feed details (title, image, full article..etc) and appending them to a new page dynamically.

Each page has an auto-generated ID, in case you want to navigate between them using *Swipe events* or any other methods.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JE2ps/)

**Code:**

```
var pageid = 0;

$('#ipaid').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
 pageid++;
 e.preventDefault();
 var clicked = $(this);
 var root = clicked.closest('li');
 var linkto = clicked.attr('href');
 var title = clicked.text();
 var date = clicked.parent('div').next('div').text();
 var linkdiv = root.find('div.itemTitle');
 var datediv = root.find('div.itemDate');
 var contentdiv = root.find('div.itemContent');
 var image = contentdiv.first('div').find('img').attr('src');
 var article = '';
 contentdiv.find('p').each(function () {
    article += $(this).text();
});

 var newPage = $("<div data-role=page id='page" + pageid + "'><div data-role=header><a data-iconpos='left' data-icon='back' href='#' data-role='button' data-rel='back'>Back</a><h1>" + title + "</h1></div><div data-role=content><p>Date:" + date + "</p><img src='" + image + "'></div><div class='article'><p>" + article + "</p></div></div></div");

 newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

 $.mobile.changePage('#page' + pageid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simple need [jFeed](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed). Sample code from the jFeed site:

```
jQuery.getFeed(options);

   options:

   * url: the feed URL (required).
   * data: data to be sent to the server. See jQuery.ajax data property.
   * success: a function to be called if the request succeeds.
     The function gets passed one argument: the JFeed object.

   Example:

   jQuery.getFeed({
       url: 'rss.xml',
       success: function(feed) {
           alert(feed.title);
       }
   });
```

Comment: I have a good feed from FeedEk, it works well. All i want to do is once a user click on a link it takes them to a specific page and then get that link title and content

Comment: Here is where is think am having issues `if($('.'+id).click() == true){
                    $('#post').empty();
                    var postTitle = title[id];
                    var postContent = content[id];
                    $('#post').append('<div><h3>'+postTitle+'</h3></div><div>'+postContent+'</div>');
                }`

Comment: Then simple use the [`onclick`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) event and [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) javascript function! `window.navigate("someURL");` is also good, if you don't need a new window...

Comment: `output += '<a href="#postContent" class="ItemTitle '+id+'">'+entry.title+'</a>';` Once the link is clicked, it will take them to #postContent page, then inside #postContent there is a #post, i want the title and content of that clicked link to appear there, rather i get the lasted title and content of output var there